# Karate - How to get the value of a specific attribute based on multiple attribute values in the specifc json array

Tags: karate

From Below Json response, based on conditions (if aName=='xyz' and mType=='ssa') , I want to get the value of corresponding id)

Is there any way can we achieve this? I want to use this id in subsequent requests

JSON Response

```
[
    {
        "id": "5fc13882d1b02109242ab3aa",
        "aName": "abc",
        "mType": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "id": "5fc13882d1b02109242ab3ab",
        "aName": "Medtria",
        "mType": "TrrrtV"
    },
    {
        "id": "5fc13882d1b02109242ab3ac",
        "aName": "Time Ortgf Day",
        "Type": "TrtV"
    },
    {
        "id": "5fc13882d1b02109242ab3ad",
        "aName": "Mrtgedia",
        "mType": "DIGrtgITAL"
    }   
]
```